# python: subprocess.call threads problem

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

Hello people within the while True processing never ends, even if I use q.task_done, what is wrong?

```
fileQueue = Queue()
def submit(i, q):
    global filespath
    while True:
      filename = q.get()
      retVT = subprocess.call("python abc.py -f %s" % (filespath + filename), shell=True, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
      retTH = subprocess.call("python def.py -a %s" % (filename), shell= True, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
      q.task_done()
```

def main():
    global fileQueue
    num_threads = fileQueue.qsize()
    for i in range(num_threads):
       worker = Thread(target=submit, args=(i, fileQueue))
       worker.setDaemon(True)
       worker.start()
    fileQueue.join()
    print "Done"

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the program listings for abc.py and def.py?  Are you sure that the commands you are executing ever end?  Try running it with the two subprocess.call() lines commented out and see if it works as intended.  If it suddenly works, then the problem is somewhere related to the scripts you're calling outside of the code.

Comment: I'll try it and then give feedback ... Thanks